# Storing collections of binaries that update infrequently in a git repository

Tags: git, github, assets, git-submodules, atlassian-sourcetree

I come from a p4 background, so apologies for the newbie git question.

What would be the best way to organize infrequently updated binary files as part of a git repo? These assets may be part of a build system and is required to exist alongside source. The bottome line is to get a complete build environment with a single clone. I'm aware of git extensions that provide support for binaries, etc. but I'd like to explore a cleaner solution with vanilla git if possible as I'm not sure if IDEs such as SourceTree support them out of them box.

Example scenario:
- Project X has binary asset collections Av1, Bv1, Cv1
- Six months later Av2, Bv2 become available
- Delete Av1, Bv1 and add Av2, Bv2

Simply keeping those assets as part of the parent repo is the obvious solution. But AFAIK all history is maintained in the repo, so even deleted assets are never really gone. This is something I want to avoid. Is there a way to selectively purge folders/files from a repo?

The recommended approach for binaries seems to be the use of submodules. I was thinking of keeping each version of the assets as their own repo and submodule them into the parent repo. With submodules, each versioned collection of assets will be in its own repo. However, do the histories/copies stick around when submodule repos are deleted?

Which is better? Are there other approaches? Does anyone have firsthand experience with a comparable scenario?

Comment: Using submodules in that way is very bizarre.  Git is very different from Perforce.  For something where you are keeping binaries around, and don't want to copy history to the client, you can either use Git Annex or you can abandon Git altogether.  Both are viable solutions.  I don't see a problem with using SVN for dependent binaries or something.

Comment: Submodules are evil - I wish they worked the way one would expect. I would suggest simply placing your binaries in the main repo.